# Computing distance between two points following network and doing it for 100.000 points?

Tags: pyqgis, distance, routing

My starting data :

- a collection of points which are buildings
- a collection of points which are electrical transformation plant
- a network of vectors which is the public electric network from an operator
- buildings are not connected to the electric network

I use QGIS to find which are the buildings which are located less than 250 meters
from an electrical transformation plant by following the network. I need this information more 100.000 buildings.

*To do it by hand :*

- trace a line between the building and the nearest electrical network segment,
- compute the distance by the network between this entry point and the nearest tranformation plant.
  I have found the RoadGraph plugin (http://gis-lab.info/qa/road-graph-eng.html) which works for that
- add the two distances and check if < 250m.

Now, my question is: how to automatize it for the 99.999 other buildings ?
I know Python a lot but I am a beginner with QGIS. I did not find a way to automatically interact 
with the RoadGraph plugin and source code seems not to be available anymore.

Maybe I am doing it wrong ?

[image: what it looks like]

Comment: is your data in PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, they are in fields associated to the layers via attribute tables. If it can help, I think I would be able to export them to pgSQL.

Comment: so your data comes from shapefiles?

Answer (score 1):

The PostGIS extension of PostgreSQL contains an executable (shp2pgsql) to import shapefiles (.shp) to PostgreSQL.

The pgRouting extension contains functions for the routing of networks (ways), such as pgr_dijkstra().

You could either write a stored procedure to do the automation or use python to access and automate the functions.